# How to use Expression to get Func<ProductModel, int> by a specific string?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

I have following ProductModel and dictionary for SumGetters

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public int Column1 { get; internal set; }
    public int Column2 { get; internal set; }
    public int Column3 { get; internal set; }
}

private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<ProductModel, int>> SumGetters = new Dictionary<string, Func<ProductModel, int>>
{
    { "Column1", model => model.Column1},
    { "Column2", model => model.Column2},
    { "Column3", model => model.Column3},
};
```

I try to get specific column from string.

Ex. if string is Column1, then get `model=>model.Column1`

How to use Expression Tree to achieve this function ?

```
Func<ProductModel, int> sumGetter;
var isGettingSumGetter = SumGetters.TryGetValue(request.Column, out sumGetter);
```

Comment: So, given a `"Column1"` string and a `ProductModel` type you want a `model => model.Column1` expression?

Comment: @xanatos Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what you are asking, BUT perhaps this is what you want:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<ProductModel, int>> productModelGettersCache = new Dictionary<string, Func<ProductModel, int>>();

public static Func<ProductModel, int> GetGetter(string column)
{
    Func<ProductModel, int> getter;

    if (!productModelGettersCache.TryGetValue(column, out getter))
    {
        var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductModel));
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductModel, int>>(Expression.Property(par, column), par);
        getter = exp.Compile();
    }

    return getter;
}
```

Note that creating and compiling an expression tree is "slow", so I'm caching the created expressions. If you only want the expression tree *before* compilation, then you can find it in `exp`.